# selected date is show on landscape orientation in android app

Tags: android, adapter, android-calendar

I have to develop an android calendar application.

I have to run my application, showing the calender. Defaultly today date is highlighted with blue colour. Now I wish to select the any other date means that selected date is highlight to blue colour.it's perfectly working in portrait mode. if I have selected other date on portrait mode and change the orientation means that selected date only have to highlight with blue background. But in my application today date only highlighted with blue background. Please check my code and provide me a solution ? Why it's happening like?

**The selected date have to highlight with blue colour background when change the orientation**. How can i do?

I have using the following code:

```
    public class CalendarView extends Activity {

public GregorianCalendar month, itemmonth;// calendar instances.

public CalendarAdapter adapter;// adapter instance
public Handler handler;// for grabbing some event values for showing the dot
                        // marker.
public ArrayList<String> items; // container to store calendar items which

ArrayList<String> event;
ArrayList<String> date;
ArrayList<String> desc;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    itemmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, month);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(calendarUpdater);
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
    RelativeLayout previous = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setPreviousMonth();
            refreshCalendar();
        }
    });

    RelativeLayout next = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNextMonth();
            refreshCalendar();

        }
    });

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            desc = new ArrayList<String>();
            date = new ArrayList<String>();
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
            String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                    .get(position);
            String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
            String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                    "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
            int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
            // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
            if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

            for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                if (Utility.startDates.get(i).equals(selectedGridDate)) {
                    desc.add(Utility.nameOfEvent.get(i));
                }
            }

            if (desc.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < desc.size(); i++) {
                    TextView rowTextView = new TextView(CalendarView.this);

                    // set some properties of rowTextView or something
                    rowTextView.setText("Event:" + desc.get(i));
                    rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    // add the textview to the linearlayout
                //  rLayout.addView(rowTextView);

                }
            }
            desc = null;
        }
    });
}

protected void setNextMonth() {
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + 1),
                month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
    }

}

protected void setPreviousMonth() {
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
    }

}

protected void showToast(String string) {
    Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void refreshCalendar() {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    adapter.refreshDays();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    handler.post(calendarUpdater); // generate some calendar items
    title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
}

public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        items.clear();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        String itemvalue;
        event = Utility.readCalendarEvent(CalendarView.this);
        Log.d("=====Event====", event.toString());
        Log.d("=====Date ARRAY====", Utility.startDates.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
            itemvalue = df.format(itemmonth.getTime());
            itemmonth.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            items.add(Utility.startDates.get(i).toString());
        }
        adapter.setItems(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
}
```

This is my adapter class :

```
    public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

private java.util.Calendar month;
public GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
/**
 * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
 */
public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
int firstDay;
int maxWeeknumber;
int maxP;
int calMaxP;
int lastWeekDay;
int leftDays;
int mnthlength;
String itemvalue, curentDateString;
DateFormat df;
private ArrayList<String> items;
public static List<String> dayString;
private View previousView;

public CalendarAdapter(Context c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar) {
    CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    month = monthCalendar;
    selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
    mContext = c;
    month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
    refreshDays();
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
    for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
            items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
        }
    }
    this.items = items;
}

public int getCount() {
    return dayString.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dayString.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    TextView dayView;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

    }
    dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    // separates daystring into parts.
    String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
    // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
    String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
    // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
    if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
        // setting offdays to white color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else {
        // setting curent month's days in blue color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
        setSelected(v);
        previousView = v;
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
    }
    dayView.setText(gridvalue);

    // create date string for comparison
    String date = dayString.get(position);

    if (date.length() == 1) {
        date = "0" + date;
    }
    String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
    if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
        monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
    }

    // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
    // 
    ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
    if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
        iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    return v;
}

public View setSelected(View view) {
    if (previousView != null) {
        previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
    }
    previousView = view;
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
    return view;
}

public void refreshDays() {
    // clear items
    items.clear();
    dayString.clear();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
    // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
    firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // finding number of weeks in current month.
    maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
    mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
    maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
    calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
    /**
     * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
     * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
     */
    pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
    /**
     * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
     */
    pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

    /**
     * filling calendar gridview.
     */
    for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {
        itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
        pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
        dayString.add(itemvalue);
    }
}

private int getMaxP() {
    int maxP;
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
    }
    maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return maxP;
}}
```

What's wrong in my login and code?

In **Manifest** file i have added below code also:

```
     <activity
    android:name=".CalendarView"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the Orientation then Android restarts the running Activity (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate()) and in onCreate() you are setting the current date, that's why your application shows the todays date on orientation change.

Override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the values you want to change to the Bundle parameter like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.

  savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
  // etc.
}
```

It will get passed in to onCreate() and also onRestoreInstanceState() where you'd extract the values like this:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.

  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
}
```

You'd usually use this technique to store instance values for your application (selections, unsaved text, etc.).

Comment: I updated my code, hopefully, it will help you. If it helps, then you can accept the answer.